# how to format numbers with dots for every thousand and comma for every decimal number?

Tags: reactjs, number-formatting, periodformatter

I am making a currency converter and I need it to display the numbers with commma and periode according to european standards, like this:

1.543.456,50 € so one million, fivehundred thousand etc.

now this number is shown like this 1543456.50 €

and I am experiencing another problem, I am not allowed to type any comma or periods in my input field. I need to have it type=text, as I want the user to be able to type in the wanted number.

here is my code:

```
import React, { useId, useState } from "react";

function InputBox({
  label,
  amount,
  onAmountChange,
  onCurrencyChange,
  currencyOptions = [],
  selectedCurrency = "eur",
  amountDisabled = false,
  currencyDisabled = false,
  className = "",
}) {
  const id = useId();
  const [amountValue, setAmountValue] = useState("");

  const isEuropeanCurrency = (currency) => {
    const europeanCurrencies = [
      "eur", // Euro
      "gbp", // British Pound
      "chf", // Swiss Franc
      "sek", // Swedish Krona
      "nok", // Norwegian Krone
      "dkk", // Danish Krone
      "pln", // Polish Złoty
      "czk", // Czech Koruna
      "huf", // Hungarian Forint
      "ron", // Romanian Leu
      "bgn", // Bulgarian Lev
      "hrk", // Croatian Kuna
      "try", // Turkish Lira
      "isk", // Icelandic Króna
    ];
    return europeanCurrencies.includes(currency.toLowerCase());
  };

  const isCryptoCurrency = (currency) => {
    const cryptoCurrencies = [
      "btc", // Bitcoin
      "eth", // Ethereum
      "ltc", // Litecoin
      "xrp", // Ripple
      "bch", // Bitcoin Cash
      "ada", // Cardano
      "xlm", // Stellar
      "dot", // Polkadot
      "link", // Chainlink
      "bnb", // Binance Coin
    ];
    return cryptoCurrencies.includes(currency.toLowerCase());
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    //Allow only numeric and specific control keys
    const isAllowedKey =
      e.key === "," || // Allow comma
      e.key === "." || // Allow dot
      (e.key >= "0" && e.key <= "9") ||
      e.key === "Backspace" ||
      e.key === "Delete" ||
      e.key === "ArrowLeft" ||
      e.key === "ArrowRight" ||
      e.key === "Home" ||
      e.key === "End";
    if (!isAllowedKey) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  const handleInputClick = () => {
    setAmountValue("");
  };

  return (
    <div className={`bg-white p-3 rounded-lg text-sm flex ${className}`}>
      <div className="w-1-2">
        <label htmlFor={id} className="text-black/40 mb-2 inline-block">
          {label}
        </label>
        <input
          id={id}
          type="text"
          className="outline-none w-full bg-transparent py-1.5"
          placeholder="Amount"
          disabled={amountDisabled}
          value={amount}
          onChange={(e) => {
            // Allow only numbers, commas, and dots
            const numericValue = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, "");

            // Attempt to convert the numeric value to a number
            const parsedValue = Number(numericValue);

            // Check if the conversion is successful
            if (!isNaN(parsedValue)) {
              // Update the state with the parsed numeric value
              onAmountChange && onAmountChange(parsedValue);
            } else {
              // If the conversion fails, set an empty string or the original value
              setAmountValue(e.target.value);
            }
          }}
          onClick={handleInputClick} // Handle click event to reset the value
        />
      </div>
      <div className="w-1/2 flex flex-wrap justify-end text-right">
        <p className="text-black/40 mb-2 w-full">Currency Type</p>
        <select
          className="rounded-lg px-1 py-1 bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer outline-none"
          value={selectedCurrency}
          onChange={(e) => {
            onCurrencyChange && onCurrencyChange(e.target.value);
          }}
          disabled={currencyDisabled}
        >
          {currencyOptions
            .filter(
              (currency) =>
                isEuropeanCurrency(currency) || isCryptoCurrency(currency)
            )
            .map((currency) => (
              <option key={currency} value={currency}>
                {currency}
              </option>
            ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default InputBox;
```

I have tried importing Numeral for React, however it does not provide a solution for the european standards but only the american periode and comma notation.

I have also tried to make it work with javascript code as you can see in my code, however it is not applied in the browser.

Thank you so much for any help or advise!

Comment: I think this is not specific to React, but should have an easy out-of-the-box solution in vanilla JavaScript

Comment: Yes I thought so to. I feel like I've tried it already, but maybe it was an error in my code that blocked the application of it. I googled again and found this article I will try and apply to the code later: https://byby.dev/js-format-numbers-commas

Answer (score 0):

```js
let num = 10000500.2;
let formattedNum = num.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
console.log(formattedNum);
```

Comment: Hi SJai, yes I got that working, my problem is I need for it to work with  spansih/european standards, so the number should be 10.000.500,20